# XSLT for selecting specific elements and attributes and outputing to csv

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to transform some of the output of a wireshark xml output file(pdml) to a csv file.

I would like to select proto elements where the attribute name = jen.   That xml should have a child element named field where the show="Discovery JEN::Item1".  From that same node I would like to

packets where the copy the following things from the following xml into one line to make .

- Extract the show attribute from a field element with show  = "item1ID" and all of its
  children element show attributes.  So the output would be the show attributes e.g. item1ID LCMI siteID: 0 applicationID: 0 objectID: 1
- Extract the child showname attributes of the field with show="ODS ID".  This would look like "HostIP: 192.168.111.72 (192.168.111.72) ProcessID: 9588 Process Create Time Sec: 1396466786 counter: 2"
- There is a field element with the attribute show = "MIPSI mipsi" and a child element field with the attribute show="Time time".  I would like to extract the attribute of the child field element of those two.  The attribute looks like show = "nanosecondsSince1970: 1396466786788509000"

I've written a little xslt before.  But this is beyond me.

I realize I would write something like the following to at least match the protocol template.  Once inside that I know I need to select field elements but once again I need to also select based upon an attribute.  Sorry what I've tried is so sparse.  I'm really lost on this point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="packet/proto[@name="jen]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@show='Discovery OMName: JEN-Item1-v4 OMTypeName: JEN::Item1']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@show"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@show='item1ID']">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@show='JEN Update Header']">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@show='MIPSI mipsi']">
    <xsl:template match="field[@show='Time time']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***XML example***

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pdml2html.xsl"?>

<pdml version="0" creator="wireshark/1.10.10" time="Mon Oct 20 16:46:32 2014" capture_file="C:\Users\someone\Documents\ABC\Test Files\ToSave\Item1_multicast.pcapng">
<packet>
<proto name="jen" showname="JEN" size="501" pos="134">
    <field name="" show="Header Data" size="0" pos="134" value="">
      <field name="" show="TAO RTEC Event Header" size="0" pos="134" value="">
        <field name="" show="Number Of Events: 1" size="4" pos="134" value="01000000"/>
        <field name="" show="EventType: ReflectionMessageEvent_t" size="4" pos="142" value="e8030000">
          <field name="jen.eventType" showname="Event Type: 30" size="4" pos="280" show="30" value="1e000000"/>
        </field>
      </field>
      <field name="jen.payloadtype" showname="Payload Type: 0" size="4" pos="218" show="0" value="00000000"/>
    </field>
    <field name="" show="Discovery OMName: JEN-Item1-v4 OMTypeName: JEN::Item1" size="8" pos="426" value="3421836700000000"/>
    <field name="" show="Discovery JEN::Item1" size="0" pos="434" value="">

      <field name="" show="item1ID" size="0" pos="442" value="">
        <field name="" show="LCMI" size="1" pos="442" value="73"/>
        <field name="" show="siteID: 0" size="2" pos="444" value="0000"/>
        <field name="" show="applicationID: 0" size="2" pos="446" value="0000"/>
        <field name="" show="objectID: 1" size="4" pos="450" value="01000000"/>
      </field>

    <field name="" show="JEN Update Header" size="0" pos="476" value="">
      <field name="" show="ODS ID" size="0" pos="476" value="">
        <field name="jen.ods.hostip" showname="HostIP: 192.168.111.72 (192.168.111.72)" size="4" pos="478" show="192.168.111.72" value="c0a86f48"/>
        <field name="jen.ods.process" showname="ProcessID: 9588" size="4" pos="482" show="9588" value="74250000"/>
        <field name="jen.ods.time" showname="Process Create Time Sec: 1396466786" size="4" pos="486" show="1396466786" value="62643c53"/>
        <field name="jen.ods.counter" showname="counter: 2" size="4" pos="490" show="2" value="02000000"/>
      </field>      
    </field>
    <field name="" show="JEN::Item1 0-0-1" size="0" pos="530" value="">
      <field name="" show="length: 81" size="4" pos="534" value="51000000"/>

      <field name="" show="JENAffiliation affiliation=Affiliation_Unknown" size="4" pos="542" value="00000000"/>

      <field name="" show="MIPSI mipsi" size="0" pos="554" value="">
        <field name="" show="LCMI" size="1" pos="554" value="73"/>
        <field name="" show="Optional Attribute Bit Set" size="1" pos="555" value="00"/>
        <field name="" show="Time time" size="0" pos="556" value="">          
          <field name="" show="nanosecondsSince1970: 1396466786788509000" size="8" pos="562" value="480529cf243f6113"/>
        </field>
      </field>
    </field>
  </proto>
</packet>
</pdml>
```

---

The Desired output would look something like the following

Discovery OMName: JEN-Item1-v4 OMTypeName: JEN::Item1, siteID: 0 applicationID: 0 objectID: 1, HostIP: 192.168.111.72 (192.168.111.72) ProcessID: 9588 Process Create Time Sec: 1396466786 counter: 2, nanosecondsSince1970: 1396466786788509000

Comment: Your goal is not clear. What do you want to extract from the fields you mention?

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Sorry,  I just edited it to display more information.  Hopefully,  between the desired output and that information it is more clear.

Comment: I am afraid I am still not following: you say "*Extract the show attribute from a field element with show =...*". There is nothing to extract here; you already know what the `show` attribute contains.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you for helping to make this more clear.  I made it a bit more verbose.  Hopefully you can understand more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: if you want your output to be CSV, then set your output method to "text", and do not copy elements of the source XML.

Here's something you could use as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="pdml/packet/proto[@name='jen']">
        <xsl:text>Discovery OMName: JEN-Item1-v4 OMTypeName: JEN::Item1,</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>item1ID,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="field[@show='item1ID']/field">
            <xsl:value-of select="@show"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- more of the same -->

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input (after correcting the malformed part!), this returns:

```
Discovery OMName: JEN-Item1-v4 OMTypeName: JEN::Item1,item1ID,LCMI,siteID: 0,applicationID: 0,objectID: 1,
```

The rest should be pretty obvious, I think.